# Translate ssh tunnel command to SSHTunnelForwarder code?

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to convert this ssh tunnel command to use python SSHTunnelForwarder. This works:

```
ssh -i mypk -N -L 5901:localhost:5432 user@100.0.0.100
```

I tried this:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('localhost', 5901),
        ssh_username='user',
        ssh_private_key=path_to_mypk,
        remote_bind_address=('100.0.0.100', 5432)
```

But get error (after it pauses for many seconds): "Could not establish session to SSH gateway". What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

The part I was missing was to use "localhost" from server's perspective. The following works:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('100.0.0.100', 22),
        ssh_username='user',
        ssh_private_key=path_to_mypk,
        remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432), # localhost from server's perspective
        local_bind_address=('localhost', 5901)  # any available port
)
```